# I'm trying to return a randomly generated number in a function so i can do some maths with it

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a function that randomly generates a number so another function can manipulate it. I got it to do what it needs to do but the next function returns an error "variable not defined", I'm guessing that the variable only exists in the scope

I've tried using the return statement at the end but it's not returning for some reason

```
import random

def generator1(): #name of function
    die_total = 0 #used for iteration
    for generator1 in range(2): #loop,generates 2 numbers
        die_roll = random.randint(1,6) #random int generator

        if die_roll % 2 == 0: # depending wether the random is odd or even,5 0r 10 is added
            die_roll += 10
        else:
            die_roll += 5

        die_total += die_roll #used to itterate and obtain a total

    return die_total #the problem,trying to return value of die_total

generator1()

print(die_total)
```

I expected a random value when I print.

Comment: I suggest you read about variable scopes i.E global and local variables.

Answer (score 1):

`die_total` exists only inside your `generator1` function (it's a local variable for it). You can use the return value though

```
print(generator1())
```

or put it in a variable

```
your_variable = generator1()
print(your_variable)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but when I run both codes, <function generator1 at 0x00FA0810>  ,or none is printed

Comment: @Silver do you still have the `return` in your `generator` function as in the sample code in your question?

Comment: I've just tried and it works. Have you made some changes?

Comment: I've removed the return statement and tats all that I'vve changed

Comment: Nope, you need the return statement :)

Comment: you function computes a value and returns it to the caller

Comment: The caller prints that value